# Make divs within a container only take up necessary space

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to created some images with dashes between them and where each div only takes up the necessary space within the container. However, from what I've attempted they all take up an even amount of space, when this shouldn't be the case for the last div. The width of the hr is 100% so in some cases this no longer shows up if the width of the div isn't defined.

How could I fix this?

Current result:
[image]

Code:

```css
.hr {
border-top: 10px dashed black; 
background-color:transparent;

.div2 {
align-items: center;
padding: 0;
flex-grow: 1;
margin-bottom: 0;
display: inline-flex;
}

.div1 {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
left: 0;
right: 0;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
display: flex;

}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
 <div class="div2">
  <img src="circle.svg">
  <hr class="hr">
 </div>
 <div class="div2">
  <img src="circle.svg">
  <hr class="hr">
 </div>
 <div class="div2">
  <img src="circle.svg">
  <hr class="hr">
 </div>
 <div class="div2">
  <img src="circle.svg">
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `flex-shrink: 1;` to `.div2` to allow them to get smaller